# Hashing into 7-Bucket table using Open and Closed hash tables

Tags: hash

I am working on some questions about open and closed hash tables, and have run into a problem. 
I have to show how the 7-bucket hash table looks when it is filled in using Open hashing, and closed hashing, using the following input.
1,8,27,64,125,516,343

With the hash function h(k) = k mod 7

I believe that for open hashing, the resulting table would look like this:

**0** -> 343

**1** -> 1 -> 8 -> 64

**2** ->

**3** ->

**4** ->

**5** ->

**6** -> 27 -> 125 -> 216

I understand this type of table. However, for a closed table, I know that you are supposed to just stick the item in the next available bucket. I have included what I think the closed hash table should look like, right before you go to insert 125.

**0** ->

**1** -> 1

**2** -> 8

**3** -> 64

**4** ->

**5** ->

**6** -> 27

So now I have to insert 125. 125 mod 7 is 6. But there is a collision in the 6 bucket. So now I would move to the next open bucket. But there isn't one. Do I just restart at the beginning of the hash table, and insert it into bucket 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would "loop" around and start at the beginning. There's a very good explanation of [*linear probing* here](http://www.cs.rmit.edu.au/online/blackboard/chapter/05/documents/contribute/chapter/05/linear-probing.html):

> Consider the situation mentioned above where data 'F' has the same hash code as data 'D'. In order to resolve the collision, the add algorithm will need to probe the table in order to find the first free space (after 'C').

[image: Linear probing example]

> Consider the situation mentioned above where data 'F' has the same hash code as data 'D'. In order to resolve the collision, the add algorithm will need to probe the table in order to find the first free space (after 'C').

[image: Linear probing example]

> If the probe loops back, and finally reaches the same element that it started at, it means that the hash table is full, and can no longer hold any more data. The addition operation will fail.

[image: Linear probing example]